# Or-tools model label solution with contraints not respected as "OPTIMAL"

Tags: mathematical-optimization, or-tools

I was trying a new MILP model and kept getting strange errors. Probably this model needs some corrections, maybe some constraints are in conflict with each other. After selecting an OPTIMAL solution I tried to check again if all the constraints were met and found that they were not. Is this behavior normal? Why is the solution considered OPTIMAL if the constraints are not met?

Also, I was wondering if there are any tools that can help me debug MILP models in or-tools.

Thanks

Comment: Typically, if hard constraints cannot be met, OR tools returns `infeasible`. Can you provide an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All MIP solvers use tolerances for computation.

The obvious example is

```
   100000 * bool_var + 1 == 100000
```

will happily return OPTIMAL with bool_var = 1 - 1e-5.

Furthermore using a large range of coefficients/bounds leads to lots of numerical errors. So they make tradeoffs. Exactness vs number of problems approximately solved.

So, reduce your ranges, and look at the violated constraints.

If you want exact computation and your problem is integral, you can use CP-SAT to solve it. It is a very good (non mixed) integer solver.

Comment: I guess this is what they call the [trickle flow issue](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/why-does-binary-or-integer-variable-take-noninteger-value-solution)